# How do you identify who owns territory on the map in Civilization V?

Tags: civilization-5

When I'm exploring the world I come across the borders of other civilizations and city states. So far I've picked up that civilizations seem to have solid borders while city states have a dashed appearance.

But how do I know whose borders they are? If I'm lucky I can see a city inside or maybe a unit working a tile, but if there are no cities or units in my line of sight and I hover my mouse I can only see the food/gold/hammers of the tile, but not who owns it.

How do I find out who owns a tile without memorizing which shade of red corresponds to which civilization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hover the mouse pointer over the tile you are interested in. After a couple of seconds a popup will appear over the tile, and it will include a line in the form of "owned by England".

So in effect there are two separate "tile information" windows - the one which appears immediately in the bottom-right, and another which appears over the tile itself after hovering. Confusing indeed :)

Comment: To add on to this, in the options menu, I'm fairly certain you can lower the time before the tooltip pops up, as mine pops up instantly. I haven't messed around with settings in a long time though, but I'm pretty sure I changed mine in there.

Comment: And finally, aren't each civ's colors unique?

Comment: @Raven it takes a long time to remember them all, though, and some civs have nearly-identical colors anyway.